# About iteration and geometry

Tags: geometry

$k$ is in $\mathbb{N}^*$ and $n=0$. We start with a man facing any direction. At step $n$, we rotate the direction of this man $n^k$ degrees to right, then then go 10 m forward. We repeat this operation (rotate direction of man to $(n+1)^k$ degrees to right, then go 10 m forward). The traces of man will loop.

For example $k=2$,use this code:

```
import turtle
turtle.pensize(3)
turtle.pencolor('black')
turtle.speed(2000)
n=0
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(-100,320)
turtle.pd()
while True:
    pn=n*n
    turtle.right(pn)
    turtle.forward(5)
    n=n+1
    if n>=2300:
        break
turtle.done()
```

It paint this picture:

[image]

The picture repeats such a shape:

[image]

When $k \le 5$ it will loop.But not loop when $k>5$ (when $k=6$,it will draw a circle at start).

Why?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Incomprehensible. What's a pen? How can $n=n+1$?

Comment: At the $n$-th step of [iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop), when you "rotate your [pen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pen) $n^k$ to the right", in which unit is your angle of rotation?

Comment: When the turtle turns to the right, does it move foward also, or is the turn made without moving?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because problem is incomprehensible.

Comment: There may be a good math question hidden here, but you're not making it easy to find it.